# CSS: background-image inside another image (or canvas)

Tags: css, canvas, html5-canvas, background-image

Is there a way to set a background-image to fit inside another image?
This example explains it all:

[image]

Comment: You can have multiple background-image rules on the same element, so yes.

Comment: **No, that image does not adequately explain!** The image will rarely be an exact fit to your speech bubble. When it's not an exact fit it must be scaled. When it's scaled there will almost always be overflow or underflow. What is to be done with the overflow or underflow?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, assuming your png has a transparent section. If you can make the images the correct size, the first option will work. The second option ensures that one aligns left and the second aligns to the right. Depending on your requirements, you may need to add padding to the second image and possibly scale it to the correct size.

```
comment {background-image: url("bubble.png"), url("people.png");}
```

or for more control

```
 comment {
       background-image: url("bubble.png") left top no-repeat, url("people.png") right top no-repeat;
    }
```

And now with an offset and pixel size for the inserted image:

```
 comment {
       background-image: url("bubble.png") left top no-repeat, url("people.png") left 30px top 20px / 300px 200px no-repeat ;
    }
```

for more details see [css3.com](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Comment: But would the second be INSIDE the other one?

Comment: revised example - you need to have a transparent section in your image. If you can't control the image sizes of the inserted image, you may have FUN debugging!

Comment: Try a different image, For testing, try a solid rectangle with a transparent circle. I took your images and overlayed them in Gimp and I could barely see the single pixel line. Need to have a solid outline to mask the image.Until then you can't tweak the CSS